# Auto-update security

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I've found this comment: [Any reason not to allow automatic updating for an app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1970/any-reason-not-to-allow-automatic-updating-for-an-app#comment1757_1970) - is that safety feature documented anywhere ? I'm about to turn on automatic updates but I don't feel comfortable doing that without a firm proof that it won't compromise security.

Comment: I always turn it off, because I don't want all newer versions of all softwares be installed. And I don't want my data and power get consumed just for some none-sense-for-me updates (updates which fix bugs for another phone models than mine). Also I prefer to review list of updates available and decide by myself which one to update.

Comment: Plus there were reports that auto-updates also happen when on mobile data -- which may harm your data plan. I also prefer to run updates when *I* decide -- and then I'm either connected by Wifi, or run a single (urgent) update manually. BTW: The "manual update" in the screenshot you refer to *is* a security feature: That app had added new permission requirements. In such a case, no automatic update will take place.

Comment: @Izzy You can tell the play store to do auto updates only when connected to WiFi.

Comment: @Flow I know -- but as I wrote: "there were reports..." that this seems to have not always been honored. Maybe just rumors ;)

Comment: @Izzy - I think some of the Google apps may update even if you're on data, but I haven't experienced that sort of thing with any other apps. That may be what you've been hearing.

Comment: OK, let's drop that argument -- enough others remain valid ;)

Comment: Wow, I've been downvoted right away! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not documented somewhere. But only updates that don't change the permissions are done automatically. If there is a change, the update will have to be done manually.

But of course there is no gurantee that this will always work this way, because of bugs or design changes. If you are paranoid, turn the feature off. (But then, how could you trust Android that the permissions that are shown to you are enforced?)

Comment: Yeah, if you're going to start mistrusting Android, where do you stop? To be completely secure, throw away your phone and wrap yourself in tinfoil ;)

Comment: Those are good points, I tried it and I can see that permission escalation requires manual approval and yeah, either I trust Android or I can throw it away :)